# Apache POI update cell after finishing Webdriver test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, browser-automation, excel-2016

So this is a little complicated to explain, but I'll try my best.

I want have an excel file with a cell which I call Count, the purpose of this number is that it gets set manually so when I read data in a worksheet it reads data for that row, and at the end of the test I want to add one onto that number.

```
    public String[] readNewHireData() {
        String ex2[] = new String[100];

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            File file = new File("C:/Users/saahme/Documents/filepath.xls");

            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            Sheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);

            Row rowCount = worksheet.getRow(1);
            Cell count = rowCount.getCell(11);
            theCount =  new BigDecimal(count.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString();

            Row row1 = worksheet.getRow(Integer.parseInt(theCount));
            Cell firstName = row1.getCell(0);
            ex2[0] = firstName.getStringCellValue();

 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ex2;
    }
```

[image]

Ok so when the test runs I want it to read theCount and that number to be 1, and that means when my test is getting the stringValue of each row its going to be 1 (I've shortened the code down to make it more readable). And once the test finishes I want it to add one onto the count. So I tried to do this.

```
 public void writeToExcel() {
        try {
            HSSFWorkbook workbook2 = new HSSFWorkbook();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/saahme/Documents/filepath.xls");
            HSSFSheet worksheet2 = workbook2.getSheetAt(1);
            HSSFRow rowCount = worksheet2.getRow(1);
            HSSFCell cellL2 = rowCount.createCell(12);
            cellL2.setCellValue(theCount + 1);
            workbook2.write(fos);

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But what I've realised is that I'm creating a new file and overwriting my old one which isnt want I want to do, I just want to edit the cell at the end of the readNewHireData and add one onto it but for the life of me whatever I'm trying does not work. I did try

```
 Row rowCount2 = worksheet.getRow(1);
            Cell count2 = rowCount2.getCell(11);
            count2.setCellValue(theCount + 1);
```

But that didnt seem to work, I feel like I'm very close to the answer here just need a hand in nudging me there. As always thanks in advance for your assistance :)

Comment: Just write the previously read workbook after updating your cells, instead of creating new one

Comment: So in the Writetoexcel method?

Comment: I suppose that's being called after the test, so yes.